# htaccess links with query strings not opening on pc,

Tags: .htaccess

my htaccess file looks like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.php$ sitemap.xml [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I want my links look like: 
https://kaznews.kz/news/477800
as they are at the time,

but when I have QUERY STRING they not opening links like: https://kaznews.kz/news/477800?google

I want either delete the ?mark and the query, or add them at the end but show the correct page.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [r=301,L,QSA]
```

this is not suitable for me because it gives me
such result: https://kaznews.kz/index.php?/news/477800&google with index.php inside, but there will be duplicate links then.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like that is roughly what you are looking for:

```
RewriteRule ^/?news/(\d+)/(.+)$ /news/$1?$2 [END,QSD]
```

That rule will internally rewrite requests to `/news/477800/google` to `/news/477800?google`.

**Update:**

From your comments below we learned that what you actually appear to ask is how you can remove, so ignore any query arguments specified in the request. Though this is a questionable thing to do (as reasoned in the comments) here is a rule to achieve that:

```
RewriteRule ^/?news/(\d+)$ /news/$1 [END,QSD]
```

**General:**

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: actually i need https://kaznews.kz/news/477800?google => https://kaznews.kz/news/477800

or https://kaznews.kz/news/477800?google => https://kaznews.kz/news/477800&google

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually mean by that. The first example you give would imply that the query string is be completely ignored, is that what you want? The second example does not make sense from a technical point of view. So: is the query string relevant for processing the request or not? If it is not, why not simply remove it? If it is, what speaks against my suggestion?

Comment: the best case is so, that kaznews.kz/news/477800?google the link would look like this but my site would also work, but at the time it is not opening such links and showing blank page.
The worst case is just remove all the signs with-after ?mark and to show the kaznews.kz/news/477800 clean url.

Comment: So you simply want to _ignore_ all query arguments. Fine. For that however you do not need any rewriting, you just have to ignore the query argument in your application. If that fails or crashes that has nothing to do with rewriting. Certainly you could remove such arguments, but wouldn't it make _much_ more sense to fix the cause of the issue instead of trying to cure the symptom?

Comment: I updated the answer and added a rule to remove / ignore such query arguments.

Comment: using latest version I have this error: 
Not Found
The requested URL /news/ was not found on this server.

for pages like https://kaznews.kz/news/479449
while, main page is working well.

Comment: I do apologize, I forgot the parenthesis. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: sorry, not working, regarding my site structure, seems it should somehow include /index.php/ inside the rewrite rule. As without my RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] rule the links like https://kaznews.kz/news/479501 are not found.

Comment: Sure, possible, I cannot tell you, only you know your site. I suggest you add that routing script to the rule. The idea of answers on SO is not to provide you with a copy and paste solution. We are trying to show up the correct path. I answered to what you actually asked. If you now realize that the situation you described is not your actual situation you need to adapt the answer.